# How to get a data from Python and send it to PHP?

Tags: php

I've been following this guide http://www.instructables.com/id/Control ... /?ALLSTEPS and everything works flawlessly. I want to edit some features of this project, using a Sense HAT instead of LEDs.

I wrote a python program to read temperature from the Sense HAT. Clicking a button in the app will run the python code. The questions is, how do I retrieve the temperature data and display it on the the web page or the android app?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python script.py');
```

i think so you can get the output of the script

Comment: I'm still new to Python, what do I need to write in the script to return the temperature reading?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @daQuincy Please note this **is not a discussion forum** where asking an indefinite series of questions is appropriate; you should take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.  Anyway, it looks to me like that php command takes the output of a python script, so the python script should just print out whatever information it is you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem so i decided to make this method this currently supports just php and python but Im coding it to support java an also javascript i will also try to see if i can do the same for c and c++

Check Out

[DATA TRANSFER PORTAL (D.T.P.)](https://github.com/omkarjc27/data-transfer-portal)  (github)

Excerpt:

> DTP is a multiprogramming , multipurpose method to conviniently transfer data between various programming languages

It requires no complex installation process.

https://github.com/omkarjc27/data-transfer-portal